# Why won't a global variable change when assigning to it in a function?

Tags: python, global-variables

I'm making a game in python, and I have some code set up as such:

```
istouching = False
death = True

def checkdead():
    if istouching:
        print "Is touching"     
        death = True

while death is False:
    print death
    # game logic
```

I know the game logic is working, because "Is touching" prints, but then when I print out the value of death, it remains false.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python function global variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588317/python-function-global-variables)

Answer (score 4):

use `global` to change global variables inside a function, otherwise `death=True` inside `checkdead()` will actually define a new local variable.

```
def checkdead():
    global death
    if istouching == True:      #use == here for comparison
        print "Is touching"     
        death = True
```

Comment: Yep. The green check-mark goes here. That one has stung me more times than I like to admit.

Comment: Better to use a return variable than modify a global.

Answer (score 4):

Make `checkdead` return a value:

```
def checkdead():
    if istouching:
        print "Is touching"     
        return True

death = checkdead()
```

You could also use `global`, as @AshwiniChaudhar shows, but I think it is preferable to write functions that return values instead of functions that modify globals, since such functions can be unit-tested more easily, and it makes explicit what external variables are changed.

PS. `if istouching = True` should have resulted in a SyntaxError since you can not make a variable assignment inside a conditional expression.

Instead, use

```
if istouching:
```

Comment: @jathanism, it's still a global. Just a different style to update it

Comment: Well, yes, but it's being explicitly mutated vs. implicitly. :)

Answer (score 2):

That's scope-related.

```
death = False        
def f():
    death = True      # Here python doesn't now death, so it creates a new, different variable
f()
print(death)          # False

death = False       
def f():
    global death
    death = True
f()
print(death)      # True
```

Comment: A better solution would perhaps be to make it object-oriented and define self.death as an attribute.
To avoid 'global death', you could also add a 'return death' statement to your function.

Comment: I upvoted your comment. Why not show the object oriented approach in your answer?