# Update Pandas DF during while loop (Python3, Pandas)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Some background: My code takes user input and applies it to my DF to remove certain rows.  This process repeats as many times as the user would like.  Unfortunately, I am not sure how to update my DF within the while loop I have created so that it keeps the changes being made:

```
data = ({'hello':['the man','is a','good guy']})
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def func():
    while True:
        n = input('Words: ')
        if n == "Done":
            break  
        elif n != "Done":
            pattern = '^'+''.join('(?=.*{})'.format(word) for word in n.split())
            df[df['hello'].str.contains(pattern)==False]
```

**How do I update the DF at the end of each loop so the changes being made stay put?**

Comment: use `loc`: `df.loc[df['hello'].str.contains(pattern)==False, 'col'] = newVal`

Comment: unsure of how this code works?  can you please explain a little more if you don't mind!

Comment: `loc` uses label based indexing see the docs: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#different-choices-for-indexing-loc-iloc-and-ix

Comment: Your code throws an error value for me

Comment: And the error is....

Comment: Ha, sorry that would have been helpful!  its a Name Error: name 'newVal' is not defined

Comment: Sorry you misunderstand, my code snippet was just an example, your code seems incomplete as you are talking about assigning values but I don't see where this occurs

Comment: Hi Ed -- There assigning values comes by means of the user inputted string:  So for example if n = the man, that row in the DF gets removed by means of a regex.  My need is to then update the DF so that row is permanently removed because there may be multiple user inputs for rows to be taken out!

Comment: You can replace your wacky `elif` construction with a simple `else` in this case. (Or, in fact, with nothing at all. The `break` takes care of the else for you.) Go ahead and do it, it'll stop future readers of this question being distracted by it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I reevaluated your problem and my old answer was totally wrong of course.

What you want is the [`DataFrame.drop method`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html). This can be done inplace.

```
mask = df['hello'].str.contains(pattern)
df.drop(mask, inplace=True)
```

This will update your DataFrame.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you've already done all the hard work, but there are two problems.

1. Your last line doesn't store the result anywhere. Most Pandas operations are not "in-place", which means you have to store the result somewhere to be able to use it later.
2. `df` is a global variable, and setting its value inside a function doesn't work, unless you explicitly have a line stating `global df`. *See the good answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10588317/2071807) for more detail.*

So I think you just need to do:

```
df = df[df['hello'].str.contains(pattern)==False]
```

to fix problem one.

For problem two, at the end of `func`, do `return df` then when you call `func` call it like:

```
df = func(df)
```

OR, start `func` with the line

```
global df
```