# Changing values in a function, but not able to print them outside of the function

Tags: python, python-2.7

Simple python code

```
def m(x,y):
  x=2
  y=[3,5]

a=1
b=[0,26]
print m(a,b)
```

I want to change the arguments,if it is possible without return.When I run my code

```
python d1.py 
None
```

Why?
With return

```
def m(x,y):
  x=2
  y=[3,5]
  return x,y

a=1
b=[0,26]
print m(a,b)
```

I got

```
(2, [3, 5])
```

What I want is a and b printed.

Comment: What do you want it to print?

Comment: Your question, and especially the title, is very unclear, but you probably want `m()` to `return` something.

Comment: Because all functions implicitly return `None` and you've printed return value from your function?

Comment: As your `definition` does not `return` anything (`None`) it will print that out.

Comment: I am confused, why are you surprised that you get `(2,[3,5])` as an output? Please describe what you want your function to do in an understandable way.

Comment: Do you want to change the value of `a` and `b` within the function? In general this is not possible, but can work around this problem thanks to mutable types (such as lists). If you explain what you are trying to accomplish, we can work towards a solution

Comment: To change **global** variables you [need to use `global a,b`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588317/python-function-global-variables). But I do not know what you want good enough to give a useful answer...

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini it is possible using `global` as @NanderSpeerstra states. I agree with hearing the OP out though. If we can clarify the misunderstanding, that's most of the question probably solved.

Comment: @Ogaday: `global` is usually a symptom of bad design. I think beginners should not be trained to use it, also because they may face unexpected behaviors. However that's just my humble opinion :)

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini Fair enough! I've never actually used it myself, came across it recently it and it does seem like it opens up a few potential pitfalls.

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini, you're right: changing global variables is almost always a bad idea. However, in this specific question it is asked how to change variables **if possible without return** (a specific demand). You're then bound to use `global`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I assume you want to achieve is to [pass your arguments by reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_reference), so that they get changed by the function.

You cannot achieve that passing [immutable](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Data_Types#Mutable_vs_Immutable_Objects) arguments (like numbers) into your function. To deal with that, take a look at the [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-write-a-function-with-output-parameters-call-by-reference). For clarity I'd strongly advise to use solution 1, though it uses a `return` statement:

```
def m(x,y):
    x = 2
    y = [3,5]
    return x,y

a = 1
b = [0,26]
a,b = m(a,b)
print a,b
```

Achieving this "without `return`" is possible using one of the other solutions given in the documentation. From those I'd say solution 3 is preferable, though it's much less clear and straightforward than solution 1. You pass a [mutable](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Data_Types#Mutable_vs_Immutable_Objects) argument to your function, like a `list`:

```
def m(x):
    x[0] = 2
    x[1] = [3,5]

a = [1, [0,26]]
m(a)
print a
```