# Change same file-scope variable from several Python files

Tags: python

It seems that if I import the same Python file via the `import` statements from several files and change some file-scope variable in it, the reference change will not be visible to another modules while container changes will.

For example,

**First example**

**first.py**

```
import reader
import helper


reader.change_buf('modified')
helper.foo()
```

**second.py**

```
import reader


def foo():
  print(reader.BUF)
```

**reader.py**

```
buf = 'original'


def change_buf(buf):
  buf = buf
```

**Output**

```
> python first.py
original
```

**Second example**

**first.py**

```
import reader
import helper


reader.change_first_element('1')
helper.foo()
```

**second.py**

```
import reader


def foo():
  print(reader.BUF)
```

**reader.py**

```
buf = ['0', '1', '2']


def change_first_element(new_elem):
  buf[0] = new_elem
```

**Output**

```
> python first.py
['1', '1', '2']
```

Why?

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr Because you're doing different things with different behaviours.**

1. In your first example, you create a local variable `buf` in the function `change_buf`; in the second example, there is no such variable to access locally, so python descends the stack upwards looking for variables that fit your request, and finds one at the module level scope.
2. Your first example uses an assignment statement,  your second statement is fancy `setitem` notation. The behaviour is different for the two.

---

Explaining the behaviour in (1), [This question is similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588317/python-function-global-variables). If you want to access a global variable explicitly **using an assignment statement**, use the [`global` or `nonlocal` keyword](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#global), [as is done here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588317/python-function-global-variables)

From the docs:

> It would be impossible to assign to a global variable without global, although free variables may refer to globals without being declared global.

Note that your second example isn't an assignment statement; it is a method call to `__setitem__` on the variable `buf`, which happens to be type list. It might make more sense looking like this

```
foo = [3]
def set_foo():
    foo.__setitem__(0,3)
```

Now you see that `foo` is a "free variable" being referenced, and can *only* be referencing the global scope element by that name. If there was any ambiguity as to which scope `foo` belonged to, python would not be able to handle your case.

---

Python's rules about scoping can be a little complex, [but are unambiguous](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/executionmodel.html)

Answer (score 0):

Simply because in first example you are hiding the global variable `buf` behind a local one (the function parameter `buf`), while in second example the function parameter(`new_elem`) does not collide. But that's not all. In first example, you *define* the variable `buf` in a function, so it is still local by default - in second example, you *use* it since you set `buf[0]`. You must declare it `global`

You should write reader.py that way:

```
buf = 'original'

def change_buf(new_val):
    global buf
    buf = new_val
```