# Need help fixing a game I made in Python

Tags: python, pygame, global-variables, local-variables

I have been set a task to make a fruit machine game in python, however I am facing a small problem, it involves a variable. it is saying that I have referenced the variable before it's assignment, even though I have assigned it. It seems to be reading it as a local variable instead of a global variable. How do i fix this.

This is the part causing the most trouble

```
Credit = 1

def main(): #the main program
    Credit = Credit - 0.20
    print("Credit remaining = " + Credit) #tells the player the amount of credit remaining
    print("\n *** The Wheel Spins... *** \n") #Spinning the wheel
    print(input("\n (press enter to continue) \n"))
```

## error message

```
line 19, in main
   Credit = Credit - 0.20
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'Credit' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Please include the actual error message.

Comment: I have added the error message

Comment: You have to make it a global variable in order for it to act like one. You would use `global Credit`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588317/python-function-global-variables) might help you (copy-pasted below).

> If you want to simply access a global variable you just use its name. However to change its value you need to use the global keyword.
>
> E.g.

```
global someVar
someVar = 55
```

> This would change the value of the global variable to 55. Otherwise it would just assign 55 to a local variable.
>
> The order of function definition listings doesn't matter (assuming they don't refer to each other in some way), the order they are called does.

You both read **and** change the value of `Credit` you need to rewrite your code into something along the lines of:

```
def main(): #the main program(edited)
    global Credit
    Credit = Credit - 0.20
```

Answer (score 1):

Anytime you want to write to a global variable in another function in python, you should let python know you want to use the global variable. Before the first line of main insert:

```
global Credit
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't declared your variable . A variable that declared outside the function don't work into function . To use that variable you have to make the credit in this case as global variable. And then everything may become fine . All the best .

```
x = something #declearing a local variable
def something():
    global x # setting local x variable as global variable, so x can be use into as well as outside of the function
    print x
    #or do something u like .
```