# Open() and read() methods in Python not adding to list

Tags: python, list, file

First I will post my code. I feel that there's a simple answer that I'm somehow overlooking.

```
questionsList=[]
answersList=[]
def retrieveQuestions():
    f=open('Questions.txt')
    questionsList=f.read().splitlines()
    for row in f:
        questionsList.append(row)

def retrieveAnswers():
    with open('Answers.txt') as j:
        answersList=list(j.read().splitlines())

retrieveQuestions()
retrieveAnswers()
print(questionsList)
print(answersList)
```

When I run the program, I get output of 
[]
[]
I looked up multiple methods of file path, multiple ways to read and .splitlines(), and I still don't know what's wrong.

Comment: You don't modify either of the global list variables.

Comment: You might also be interested in [this article about the "nonlocal" keyword](https://www.smallsurething.com/a-quick-guide-to-nonlocal-in-python-3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, your methods only create and populate lists but nothing else -no screen output or return. Simply add a `return` to your functions and assign values to a variable and print or `print` inside each called function. And you do not need the global variable assignment at top as you define variables inside the methods.

Return and Assign

```
def retrieveQuestions():
    f=open('1222_2016_2016-2017.csv')
    questionsList=f.read().splitlines()
    for row in f:
        questionsList.append(row)
    f.close()

    return questionsList

def retrieveAnswers():
    with open('ODDFiles.csv') as j:
        answersList=list(j.read().splitlines())

    return answersList

questionsList = retrieveQuestions()
answersList = retrieveAnswers()

print(questionsList)
print(answersList)
```

Print Inside

```
def retrieveQuestions():
    f=open('1222_2016_2016-2017.csv')
    questionsList=f.read().splitlines()
    for row in f:
        questionsList.append(row)
    print(questionsList)

def retrieveAnswers():
    with open('ODDFiles.csv') as j:
        answersList=list(j.read().splitlines())
    print(answersList)

retrieveQuestions()
retrieveAnswers()
```

Comment: This works. Although why do I have to put questionsList=retrieveQuestions() ? Shouldn't the retrieveQuestions method by itself assign input to questionsList? That's what it's doing inside the function correct?

Comment: Read up on object-oriented programming. Not just Python, but in most languages, anything inside a function is local to that function and does not exist outside unless you return a value.

Comment: However, I used global lists inside the function. Why didn't that work?

Comment: As mentioned, you re-assigned inside function so global variables were not not needed, plus you did not `return` anything, also mentioned. You might be needing to use `global`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10588317/1422451).

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
questionsList=[]
answersList=[]
def retrieveQuestions():
    f=open('Questions.txt', 'r')
    questionsList = f.readlines().splitlines()

def retrieveAnswers():
    with open('Answers.txt', 'r') as j:
        answersList = j.readlines().splitlines()

retrieveQuestions()
retrieveAnswers()
print(questionsList)
print(answersList)
```

**Sugestion:**

```
def read_file(filename):
    return open(filename, 'r').readlines().splitlines()

questionsList = read_file('Questions.txt')
answersList = read_file('Answers.txt')

print(questionsList)
print(answersList)
```