# How to get input from QTextEdit in PyQt4

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4, pyqt5

**how do i solve the following problem**
i am unable to get text from QTextEdit and insert it into Database...

Code:

```
import sys
import MySQLdb
#from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

e1=None
e2=None

def window():
    app=QApplication(sys.argv)
    win=QWidget()
    win.setWindowTitle("Sample")
    vbox=QVBoxLayout()
    e1 = QTextEdit()
    e2 = QTextEdit()
    vbox.addWidget(e1)
    vbox.addWidget(e2)
    vbox.addStretch()
    b1=QPushButton("Tap it!")
    vbox.addWidget(b1)
    b1.clicked.connect(b1_action)
    win.setGeometry(100,100,200,50)
    win.setLayout(vbox)
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

def b1_action():
    print "Button Clicked"
    db = MySQLdb.connect('localhost', 'root', 'mysql', 'Tecoc354')
    cursor=db.cursor()
    x1=e1.toPlainText()
    x2=e2.toPlainText()
    print x1," ",x2," "
    #sql="create table Sample(addr varchar(10),name varchar(10))"
   # cursor.execute(sql)
    sql2="insert into Tecoc354.sample values(%s,%s)"%(x1,x2)
    cursor.execute(sql2)
    db.commit()
    db.close()

window()
```

Comment: When you ask a question, don't just say "I'm unable...." but include the exact error message or observed behaviour of your program

Comment: Just declare "global e1,e2" in window() function.

Comment: ok i will take care of this next time thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is, that in `b1_action()` the variables `e1` and `e2` are not recognized as `QTextEdit()`. Just for educational purpose add the line `print e1` to both functions. You'll get:

```
<PyQt4.QtGui.QTextEdit object at 0x01DA7490>
none
```

printed from `Window()` and `b1_action()`. So you see, in `b1_action()` `e1` is not a `QTextEdit`. `e1` / `e2` in `Window()` are not the same variables as `e1` / `e2`  in `b1_action()`

The shortest way to solve that is to make `e1` and `e2` global variables. So first delete the lines

```
e1=None
e2=None
```

and then define both variables as global inside of `Window`:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

def window():
    global e1
    global e2
    app=QApplication(sys.argv)
    win=QWidget()
    win.setWindowTitle("Sample")
    vbox=QVBoxLayout()
    e1 = QTextEdit()
    e2 = QTextEdit()
```

You can find some useful information in this question and answers about [global variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588317/python-function-global-variables)

Generally I would not recommend to build a GUI based on functions and global variables. Find a tutorial and learn how to use classes. For example [this one](http://www.rkblog.rk.edu.pl/w/p/simple-text-editor-pyqt4/)