# Python function prints output but cannot seem to return it correctly or call it after

Tags: python, function, return

I am simply attempting to append an array if it is blank and return the updated array. By doing the following, I get the array back absolutely fine if it is not blank but for the life of me I cannot return it correctly in the else part.

I can print it and it shows as an output, what am I doing wrong?

```
import numpy as np

W = np.array([])


def intitialise_W(W):
    if W.size > 0:
        W = W
        return W
    else:
        fix = np.array([0.15,0.2,0.25,0.3])
        W = np.append(W,fix)
        print(W) #Works fine
        return W


intitialise_W(W)

print(W) #produces W = [] not W = [0.15, 0.2, 0.25, 0.3] as expected
```

Thanks

Comment: You need to assigned the returned value from `initialise_W` to a variable

Comment: You need to assign your returned value to a variable name. Do for instance `result = initialize_W(W)` and then `print(result)`. Otherwise your `W` only lives within the function `initialize_W`.

Comment: You are not using the global `W` inside the `initialise_W` function. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588317/python-function-global-variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not saving the returned value from the funtion. Change to:

```
W = intitialise_W(w)
```

Then it works.

Comment: Ah thank you so much, knew it was something silly I was doing wrong

Answer (score 2):

Totally unrelated (and this should really be a comment but there's no way to post formatted code in comment so...): there are a couple useless things and potential issues with your "initialize_W()" function

```
def initialise_W(W):
    if W.size > 0:
        W = W  # => this line is totally useless
        return W # => you have one return here and...

    else:
        fix = np.array([0.15,0.2,0.25,0.3])
        W = np.append(W,fix)
        return W # you have another return here
```

Actually, what you want is : "if W is empty, initialize it (else there's nothing to do), then in both cases return W". This can be expressed in a much simpler, easier to read and maintain way:

```
def initialise_W(W):
    if W.size == 0:
        fix = np.array([0.15,0.2,0.25,0.3])
        W = np.append(W,fix)
    return W
```