# global variables inside function python 3.x

Tags: python-3.x

guys i am new in python and for some reason the word global not working for me 
ex

```
def location():  
global place
place = "Cape Town"
return
```

and when i am trying to print place

```
print(place)
```

i am facing that error

```
 NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-34a3a4594339> in <module>()
----> 1 print(place)

NameError: name 'place' is not defined
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588317/python-function-global-variables

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python function global variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588317/python-function-global-variables)

Comment: Did you ever actually call `location()` so that it could set the global variable?