# Function declaring global variable doesn't work in debug mode

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm debugging a program. In the debug console, I decided to write the following function:

```
def func():
    global a
    a=5

func()

a
```

a is undefined!

Why does this happens in the debug console?

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of this happening in the debug console?

Comment: @user2357112 Exactly what you see above.

Comment: What I see above doesn't include the error message, and is missing a lot of other useful context as well.

Comment: Sorry. Here is the error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\s4551072\.conda\envs\tfbetacpu\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3296, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-6-89e6c98d9288>", line 1, in <module>
    b
NameError: name 'a' is not defined

Comment: Other than that, it is exactly as above.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use **a** outside function, you should declare it first.

```
a = 0

def func():
    global a
    a=5

func()
print(a)
```

In this case will be 6 and 3

```
test=6
def func():
    global test
    print(test)
    test=3
f()
print(test)
```

FYI: [What are the rules for local and global variables in Python?](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python)

> In Python, variables that are only referenced inside a function are implicitly global. If a variable is assigned a value anywhere within the function’s body, it’s assumed to be a local unless explicitly declared as global.
>
> Though a bit surprising at first, a moment’s consideration explains this. On one hand, requiring global for assigned variables provides a bar against unintended side-effects. On the other hand, if global was required for all global references, you’d be using global all the time. You’d have to declare as global every reference to a built-in function or to a component of an imported module. This clutter would defeat the usefulness of the global declaration for identifying side-effects.

Comment: This is weird cause I usually don't have to declare anything first. Say if I used Jupyter, or did it in the main program.

Comment: You can also see this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588317/python-function-global-variables

Comment: There is ordinarily no need to declare the variable first. The code in the question [works fine](https://ideone.com/Kq23B5) when run as a script.

Comment: Yes I know. It only happens in debugging console.