# Pickle saving and loading problem, pygame application

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pickle

I'm doing a little random generator thing and when I'm trying to load the saved thing I run into a problem. It's not showing any errors but it's not working.
Here is my code, *at line 78 there is the loadSave function and on line 95 there is the createSave function*. Because I can't save the whole classes that are in the list I'm saving just it's values and then when I load it back I create new classes with the same values, and the **loading part is not working**, I tested it.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import simpledialog
import pygame as pg
import sys
import random
import os
import pickle

pg.init()
pg.font.init()
pg.display.set_caption("Random")

win = pg.display.set_mode((800, 600))

clock = pg.time.Clock()

isFirstDraw = True
numbers = []


def endScreen(win):
    while True:
        clock.tick(60)

        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                pg.quit()
                pg.font.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                pg.quit()
                pg.font.quit()
                sys.exit()

        win.fill((255, 255, 255))
        text = pg.font.SysFont("comicsans", 100).render("The end", True, (0, 0, 0))
        win.blit(text, (300, 235))
        pg.display.update()


def drawButtons(win, m_pos):
    if m_pos[0] >= 290 and m_pos[0] <= 490 and m_pos[1] >= 450 and m_pos[1] <= 515:
        pg.draw.rect(win, (155, 155, 155), ((290, 450), (200, 65)))
    else:
        pg.draw.rect(win, (177, 177, 177), ((290, 450), (200, 65)))

    text = pg.font.SysFont("comicsans", 25).render("Generate random", True, (0, 0, 0))
    text2 = pg.font.SysFont("comicsans", 25).render("number", True, (0, 0, 0))

    win.blit(text, (310, 455))
    win.blit(text2, (330, 485))

    ## next button

    if m_pos[0] >= 0 and m_pos[0] <= 200 and m_pos[1] >= 535 and m_pos[1] <= 600:
        pg.draw.rect(win, (155, 155, 155), ((0, 535), (200, 65)))
    else:
        pg.draw.rect(win, (177, 177, 177), ((0, 535), (200, 65)))

    text = pg.font.SysFont("comicsans", 35).render("Save", True, (0, 0, 0))

    win.blit(text, (35, 550))

    ## next button

    if m_pos[0] >= 600 and m_pos[0] <= 800 and m_pos[1] >= 535 and m_pos[1] <= 600:
        pg.draw.rect(win, (155, 155, 155), ((600, 535), (200, 65)))
    else:
        pg.draw.rect(win, (177, 177, 177), ((600, 535), (200, 65)))

    text = pg.font.SysFont(""comicsans", 25).render("Load", True, (0, 0, 0))
    text2 = pg.font.SysFont(""comicsans", 25).render("save", True, (0, 0, 0))

    win.blit(text, (670, 540))
    win.blit(text2, (660, 565))


def loadSave():
    try:
        pickle_in = open("numbers.save", "rb")
        loadNum = pickle.load(pickle_in)
        pickle_in.close()
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return numbers

    numbers = []
    print(numbers)
    for i in loadNum:
        numbers.append(Number(i[0], i[1], i[2], i[4], i[3]))



def createSave():
    try:
        os.remove("numbers.save")
    except:
        pass

    numSave = []
    for i in numbers:
        numSave.append([i.x, i.y, i.num, i.isDead, i.fontSize])

    pickle_out = open("numbers.save", "wb")
    pickle.dump(numSave, pickle_out)
    pickle_out.close()


def randomNum(win, answer, answer2):
    global randNum

    try:
        rand = random.randint(answer, answer2)

        if randNum == False:
            randNum = Number(376, 400, rand, fontSize=40)
        else:
            randNum.num = rand
        if numbers[rand - 1].isDead:
            randomNum(win, answer, answer2)
        else:
            numbers[rand - 1].isDead = True
    except RecursionError:
        endScreen(win)


class Number:
    def __init__(self, x, y, num, fontSize=40, isDead=False):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.num = num
        self.isDead = isDead
        self.text = False
        self.fontSize = fontSize

    def render(self):
        self.text = pg.font.SysFont("comicsans", self.fontSize).render(
            str(self.num), True, (0, 0, 0)
        )
        win.blit(self.text, (self.x, self.y))
        if self.isDead:
            if self.num >= 10:
                pg.draw.line(
                    win,
                    (255, 0, 0),
                    (self.x, self.y + 5),
                    (self.x + 45, self.y + 42),
                    5,
                )
                pg.draw.line(
                    win,
                    (255, 0, 0),
                    (self.x + 45, self.y + 5),
                    (self.x, self.y + 42),
                    5,
                )
            else:
                pg.draw.line(
                    win,
                    (255, 0, 0),
                    (self.x, self.y + 5),
                    (self.x + 25, self.y + 42),
                    4,
                )
                pg.draw.line(
                    win,
                    (255, 0, 0),
                    (self.x + 25, self.y + 5),
                    (self.x, self.y + 42),
                    4,
                )


def reDraw(win, anserw, anserw2, m_pos):
    global isFirstDraw, randNum
    win.fill((255, 255, 255))

    if isFirstDraw:
        previousPos = [10, 20]
        for i in range(anserw, anserw2 + 1):
            try:
                if (
                    numbers[-1].num == 15
                    or numbers[-1].num == 27
                    or numbers[-1].num == 39
                ):
                    previousPos[1] += 50
                    previousPos[0] = -45

                if numbers[-1].num >= 10:
                    numbers.append(Number(previousPos[0] + 65, previousPos[1], num=i))
                else:
                    numbers.append(Number(previousPos[0] + 45, previousPos[1], num=i))
            except:
                numbers.append(Number(previousPos[0], previousPos[1], num=i))

            if previousPos[0] >= 720:
                previousPos[1] += 50
                previousPos[0] = -45
            else:
                previousPos = [numbers[-1].x, numbers[-1].y]
        isFirstDraw = False

    for i in numbers:
        i.render()

    if randNum is not False:
        randNum.render()

    drawButtons(win, m_pos)

    pg.display.update()


def main():
    global win, isFirstDraw, randNum

    tk = Tk()
    tk.title("Input")
    tk.geometry("100x100")
    tk.withdraw()
    #'''
    answer = simpledialog.askinteger(
        "min:1, max:49", "A legkisebb szám:", parent=tk, minvalue=1, maxvalue=49
    )
    answer2 = simpledialog.askinteger(
        "min:1, max:50", "A legnagyobb szám:", parent=tk, minvalue=answer, maxvalue=50
    )  #'''
    # answer = 1
    # answer2 = 5
    tk.destroy()

    randNum = False
    numbers = []
    while True:
        clock.tick(60)
        m_pos = pg.mouse.get_pos()

        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                pg.quit()
                pg.font.quit()
                sys.exit()

            if (
                event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN
                and m_pos[0] > 290
                and m_pos[0] < 490
                and m_pos[1] > 450
                and m_pos[1] < 515
            ):
                randomNum(win, answer, answer2)
            elif (
                event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN
                and m_pos[0] >= 0
                and m_pos[0] <= 200
                and m_pos[1] >= 535
                and m_pos[1] <= 600
            ):
                createSave()
            elif (
                event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN
                and m_pos[0] >= 600
                and m_pos[0] <= 800
                and m_pos[1] >= 535
                and m_pos[1] <= 600
            ):
                numbers = loadSave()

        # print(m_pos)

        reDraw(win, answer, answer2, m_pos)


main()
```

Comment: What does not working mean ? Can you minify your code ?

Comment: @BlueSheepToken When I call the load method (loadSave) it dosen't change anything Edit: Minfied it

Comment: What is it supposed to do ? Sorry I do not get it.

Comment: Do you have discord? @BlueSheepToken

Comment: Test it what it does you have the full code. Python version: 3.4.7

Comment: As you can see from the syntax highlighting, your code is invalid. It is just one long string after ˋtext = pg.font.SysFont(""comicsans"ˋ. This includes both functions you mention.

Comment: It's not the problem it was a typo when I was editing the post.

Comment: Please help us help you and provide code that reproduces your problem. You currently require people to guess how to fix your code in such a way that it is still broken.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python function global variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588317/python-function-global-variables)

Comment: In ``loadSave``, you define a *local* variable ``numbers = []`` which shadows the global ``numbers``. You must declare ``global numbers`` in ``loadSave``.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, a variable declared outside of the function or in global scope is known as a global variable. This means that a global variable can be accessed inside or outside of the function.
A variable declared inside the function's body or in the local scope is known as a local variable.

You have to use the [`global` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=global#grammar-token-global-stmt)  if you want to be interpret the variable as global variable:

```py
def loadSave():
    global numbers # <----

    try:
        pickle_in = open("numbers.save", "rb")
        loadNum = pickle.load(pickle_in)
        pickle_in.close()
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return numbers

    numbers = []
    print(numbers)
    for i in loadNum:
        numbers.append(Number(i[0], i[1], i[2], i[4], i[3]))
```

In this case, you can avoid the `global`  statement. Instead of creating a new list (`numbers = []`), [`clear`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) the list (`numbers.clear()`):

```py
def loadSave():
    try:
        pickle_in = open("numbers.save", "rb")
        loadNum = pickle.load(pickle_in)
        pickle_in.close()
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return numbers

    numbers.clear() # <----
    print(numbers)
    for i in loadNum:
        numbers.append(Number(i[0], i[1], i[2], i[4], i[3]))
```