# Unable to assign value to global variable inside function, Python 3.8.10

Tags: python, python-3.x, global-variables, file-handling

Using Python 3.8.10,
I'm working on a simply python module (one .py file) with constants, functions and classes relevant to a physics course I'm currently taking.
Inside this module, I have a collection of global variables of "constants", such as "g" for force of gravity near earth's surface (9.8) N/kg. I'm working on a feature to modify these constants in the case of dealing with questions that involve things like "let g = 10 N/kg".
I need to incorporate reading / writing to a txt file which will store the constants, and can be modified to modify constants in the program. So I have defined a function "updateConstantsFromFile(file)" which is supposed to set all these global variables to what it reads in the file. And the crazy thing is THIS WORKS WHEN I FIRST RUN THE PROGRAM, but NOT AGAIN. I cannot understand why, I've tried many different methods of assigning global variables, none seem to work.

the function looks like this:

```
def updateConstantsFromFile(file):
    global g
    lines = file.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        varName = line.split()[0]
        value = line.split()[2]
        print(varName, value) #Always prints the correct variable name and value as expected
        if varName == "g":
            g = float(value)
```

In place of `g = float(value)` I've tried `globals()[varName] = float(value)`, `globals().__setitem__(varName, float(value)`, and `consts["g"] = float(value)` in which "consts" was a dictionary of my constants and this DID WORK, which i really don't understand.

Here is how I first call the function:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        constFile = open("constantsFile.txt", "r")
        updateConstantsFromFile(constFile)
        constFile.close()
    except FileNotFoundError:
        constFile = open("constantsFile.txt", "w")
        restoreDefaultConstants(constFile)
        constFile.close()
```

How can I update a global variable from within this function?

Comment: This seems like a poor design. Instead of setting lots of global variables, put everything in a dictionary. Then save the whole dictionary in a JSON or Pickle file.

Comment: I can't see any reason why this would only work once.

Comment: Note that if it never finds the `g` line in the file, it won't assign `g`. Do you initialize this with a default value before calling the function?

Comment: You need to provide more details about how it's failing when you run the program the second time. What happens if you put a `print()` after the `if` line?

Comment: @Barmar, I'm aware the design isn't ideal but this is for a course that has a lot of restrictions and requirements of this program, I do indeed initialize g with a default value before calling this function, having an incomplete / missing constantsFile.txt doesn't cause problems. Putting a `print()` after the first `if` behaves as expected

Comment: I've tried setting up your code as you described and running it works every time, so I cannot reproduce your issue. Try creating a reproducible minimal example from your own code and see if it happens (e.g. just the functions & statements you think are causing the problem).

Comment: Something else must be overwriting the variable if the `if` is being executed.

Comment: I suggest using a debugger and watching the variable. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7668979/how-do-you-watch-a-variable-in-pdb

Comment: I've tried all these suggestions, and it's just straight up not working. I'm using the IPython Console in Spyder, could that be causing me issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How to make global variables work in Spyder inside a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59247305/how-to-make-global-variables-work-in-spyder-inside-a-function)
It was an issue in Spyder. I needed to run in console's namespace instead of an empty one.
Option is here: Spyder/Preferences/Run/General settings/Run

Thanks to everybody who helped!