# Python creating local variable instead of using global variable

Tags: python, variables, discord.py

I'm building a Discord bot but I think this has more to do with Python than it has to do with `discord.py`

I have this function, built for identifying a server member:

```
async def targetIdentificator(ctx):
    targetArgument = ctx.message.content.lower().replace(">target", "")

    for member in ctx.message.guild.members:
        if targetArgument.lower() in member.name.lower():
            targetID = member.id
            targetName =  targetArgument
            print("targetID")
    if targetID != "":
        return targetID
    else:
        return None
```

And about 200 lines above in the code, I define two variables as such:

```
targetName = ""
targetID = ""
```

I've used these variables a lot of times throughout the code, in various other functions. In this function, what happens is that when I mention `targetID`, it references a new local variable instead of referencing the global variable. Therefore if the `if` statement inside the `for` cycle never goes through, I get this error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'targetID' referenced before assignment
```

This is probably a really simple mistake, and I apologize if so, but I've been scratching my head for so long on it and can't seem to understand why...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe this answers your question: [Python function global variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588317/python-function-global-variables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `global` [keyword](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#global) to explicitly tell Python you're referring to the global variable inside the function, like this:

```
async def targetIdentificator(ctx):
    global targetID
    global targetName

    targetArgument = ctx.message.content.lower().replace(">target", "")

    for member in ctx.message.guild.members:
        if targetArgument.lower() in member.name.lower():
            targetID = member.id
            targetName =  targetArgument
            print("targetID")
    if targetID != "":
        return targetID
    else:
        return None
```

Comment: Thanks. But how come I didn't have to do that for any other function in which I used those variables?

Comment: Yeah that was it.

Answer (score 1):

In order to change a global variable inside a local function, you need to tell python that the variable is global with the `global` statement

In this case, it should look something like:

```
async def targetIdentificator(ctx):
    global targetID
    global targetName
    ....
```