# why am i not getting the game over message in this high low code

Tags: python

```
import random
game = False
random_num = random.randint(1 , 100)
print(random_num)
x = 0
if x == 1:
    game = True
def code():
    if number == random_num :
        x + 1
        print('you von')

    elif number > random_num :
        print('lov')
    elif number < random_num :
        print('higher')

if game == True:
    print ("game over")
while x == 0:
    number = int(input("Guess the number "))
    code()
```

code should end if the correct number is guessed
game over is never printed
keeps asking me to guess the number

i also tried this code it keeps failing
pycharm greys out-> game
in if function
game = True

```
import random
game = False
random_num = random.randint(1 , 100)
print(random_num)
#x = 0
#if x == 1:
    #game = True
def code():
    if number == random_num :
        game = True
        print('you von')

    elif number > random_num :
        print('lov')
    elif number < random_num :
        print('higher')

if game == True:
    print ("game over")
while game == False:
    number = int(input("Guess the number "))
    code()
```

Comment: use `print()` to see values in variables in different moments. OR learn how to use read debuger. You never change `game` to `True` so it can't execute `print ("game over")` - beside your code seems in wrong order - you check `if game == True:` before you even start game - and later you don't check it. OR maybe you have wrong indentation and ` `if game == True:` should be inside `def code` ?

Comment: "game over is never printed " Talk me through the code, step by step, and try to convince me that it should be printed. Right now I think it definitely should not be, and I don't understand why you think it should be. I can't help you understand the problem unless I understand your thinking.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're trying to change the `game` variable, which is a `global` variable. It lives outside the scope of the `code` function.

In order to achieve what you want, you have to declare `game` as global at the beginning of the `code()` function. Otherwise, it will take `game` as fresh local variable:

```py
def code():
    global game
    [...]
```

I found this related question that you may find useful: [Python function global variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588317/python-function-global-variables)

From the [python programming FAQ](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python):

> In Python, variables that are only referenced inside a function are implicitly global. If a variable is assigned a value anywhere within the function’s body, it’s assumed to be a local unless explicitly declared as global.

Answer (score 1):

So there are a couple of things here, but the most important is that the variable x is not being returned with the new value if we guess correctly. In order to return a variable from a function with an updated variable, it needs to be returned, like so:

```
def code(x):
    if number == random_num :
        x = 1
        print('you von')

    elif number > random_num :
        print('lov')
    elif number < random_num :
        print('higher')
    return x

while x == 0:
    number = int(input("Guess the number "))
    x = code(x)
    print(x)
```

The order of the statements also means that some of them are getting skipped. When we reorder like this:

```
import random
game = False
random_num = random.randint(1 , 100)
print(random_num)
x = 0

def code(x,number):
    if number == random_num :
        x = 1
        print('you von')
    elif number > random_num :
        print('lov')
    elif number < random_num :
        print('higher')
    return x

while x == 0:
    number = int(input("Guess the number "))
    x = code(x,number)
    print(x)

if x == 1:
    game = True
if game == True:
    print ("game over")
```

We get the desired output and the program exits when the number is guessed.