# How to change a local variable from a sub-function

Tags: python

I have following code:

```
my_var=1
def a():  
    def b():
        my_var=2
    b()
    return my_var

print(a())
```

I'm trying to change the variable `my_var` in sub-function `b()`. The result should be 2 instead of 1. But in my code, it doesn't work. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You could use `global` or better return the value from the function and assign it to your variable.

Comment: oh great thank! I did not know that I also use global in sub-function Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python function global variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588317/python-function-global-variables)

Comment: Yes, but I was not sure, if it's also for sub-functions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`global` is the keyword used in python to access the actual variable which is present outside function try out the below code.

```
my_var=1
def a(): 
    def b():
        global my_var
        my_var = 2
    b()
    return my_var

print(a())
```