# Getting "local variable referenced before assignment" How do I fix this?

Tags: python, adafruit-circuitpython

```
pauseon = 1


def spin(speed):
  if pauseon == 1:
    pixels[0] = ((255,0,0));
    if button_A.value:
        pauseon = 0  
    time.sleep(0.01);
    pixels.fill((0,0,0));
    pixels[1] = ((255,2555,0));
    if button_A.value:
        pauseon = 0      
    time.sleep(0.08);
    pixels.fill((0,0,0));
    pixels[2] = ((255,105,0));
    if button_A.value:
        pauseon = 0  
    time.sleep(0.08);
    pixels.fill((0,0,0));
    pixels[3] = ((0,255,0));
    if button_A.value:
        pauseon = 0  
    time.sleep(0.08);
    pixels.fill((0,0,0));
    pixels[4] = ((0,0,255));
    if button_A.value:
        pauseon = 0  
    time.sleep(0.08);
    pixels.fill((0,0,0));
    pixels[5] = ((126,0,126));
    if button_A.value:
        pauseon = 0  
    time.sleep(0.08);
    pixels.fill((0,0,0));
    pixels[6] = ((25,140,200));
    if button_A.value:
        pauseon = 0  
    time.sleep(0.08);
    pixels.fill((0,0,0));
    pixels[7] = ((50,150,90));
    if button_A.value:
        pauseon = 0  
    time.sleep(0.08);
    #play_sound("bop.wav")
    pixels.fill((0,0,0));
    pixels[8] = ((25,25,160));
    if button_A.value:
        pauseon = 0  
    time.sleep(0.08);
    pixels.fill((0,0,0));
    pixels[9] = ((255,0,255));
    if button_A.value:
        pauseon = 0
```

I'm getting a "local variable referenced before assignment" for line 5 of this chunk of code.

I have tried other methods of doing this exact same thing but all have resulted in some sort of error. I have tried fixing this for about 2 hours now and I am still stuck. (I am a bit newer to python but I do have experience in other languages)

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588317/python-function-global-variables), you need `global pauseon` at the start of the function.

Comment: Thank you I got this to work.